# constexpr expressions with side effects? (On MSVC)

Tags: c++

I understand C++ compile-time expressions pretty well I think (famous last words).  I am seeing a behavior with *constexpr* expressions in Microsoft Visual C++ that surprises me and that I'm pretty sure is a (pretty significant IMO) bug.

My interpretation is supported by the fact that g++ behaves differently, in a way that matches my expectations/understanding.  However I'm not a spec guy so I want to make sure this isn't in some kind of "undefined behavior" gray area.

First, my overall understanding is that *constexpr* expressions (among other characteristics/limitations):

- Can have no side effects (like writing to a global variable)
- Always evaluate to the same value.  That is if the exact same expression is in two places in source code, it will not somehow evaluate to two different values.

If the above are correct, then MSVC indeed has a bug because a ***mutable*** member of a *constexpr* class instance can be modified in a *constexpr* expression - a side effect.  Its value when evaluated "after" vs. "before" this modification will be different.  ("Before" and "after" here are not the in terms of runtime execution but in terms of compile-time evaluation of *constexpr* expressions...the order of which may not even be well-defined?)

Here it is boiled down completely:

```
struct Foo
{
    mutable int m_i {1};
};

constexpr Foo f;

template <int I>                           // Template so *compile-time* value of constexpr
void Bar() {std::cout << I << std::endl;}  // expressions can be examined

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Bar<f.m_i>();        // MSVC prints "1".  g++ issues an error on this line to the
                         // effect of "mutable member data usable in a constexpr
                         // expression".  I believe g++ shows the correct behavior.

    Bar<(f.m_i = 2)>();  // MSVC prints "2".  The constexpr expression "f.m_i = 2" causes a
                         // side-effect (global value f.m_i is modified)

    Bar<f.m_i>();        // MSVC prints "2".  So the same constexpr "f.m_i" evaluates to
                         // different values depending on what has been compiled so far.
}
```

On MSVC, although the value of *f.m_i* changes depending on what has been *compiled* "so far", it is (of course) unaffected by run-time conditions and execution order:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Bar<f.m_i>();
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        Bar<(f.m_i = 2)>();
    }
    Bar<f.m_i>();            // (MSVC prints "2" regardless of runtime argc value)
}
```

Comment: there is no question

Comment: FYI: VS 15.9 prints 1,2,1

Comment: In Microsoft World this is called a feature, not a bug ;)

Comment: @Nathan - yes this is a duplicate of the question you linked to.  This can be closed as duplicate.  Thanks!

Comment: @Anton - I should have mentioned I am on VS 15.7.4 (VC++ version 14.14).  I get "1", "2", "2".  So it looks like they have semi-fixed the issue.

Comment: @Gyorgy - For the record, the question was "Is the g++ behavior correct and the VC++ behavior strictly incorrect?  Or is the example program undefined behavior?  Or am I fundamentally confused about constexpr?"

Comment: I've close the Q for you.  Thanks for the conformation.